# Maven trying to download non-existent .jar

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Whenever I try to `mvn package` with my maven 3 project I am greeted with the error

```
Failed to execute goal on project XYZ
```

and further down the error message

```
Could not find artifact X:Y:Z in maven2
```

I'm wondering a few things:

- Is it supposed to be looking in the maven2 repo if it is, in fact, maven 3? (3.0.5)
- My build worked perfectly fine (well once) until I plugged into intellij IDEA, now it fails to package (even when i build outside of IDEA), is it IDEA's fault?
- The .jar file does not, in fact, exist in the maven central repository, because the dependency I am trying to download is basically just a dependency package (is that what it's called?) It's log4j 2.0beta-7 and the directory only contains a .pom with other dependencies

I will provide the pom.xml if it turns out the error isn't just blatant stupidity on my part and could be a bug.

**EDIT**: Here is a pom http://pastebin.com/FLeVLrki

Comment: How have you declared that dependency's packaging? The default is `jar` I believe. If you don't tell Maven it's a `pom` dependency it's going to look for a JAR.

Comment: without seeing your pom.xml this is not a real question

Comment: Added the pom, see the edit

Comment: Add your POM to the question,  not as a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your dependency might be wrong.

On http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html they provide the following snippet for configuring the dependencies in maven.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta7</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This did work, however I do wonder why it wouldn't just read the .pom file?

Comment: As far is I can tell the jar cannot be found in the repositories defined in pom.xml. Searching the [central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.logging.log4j%22) also revealed only a pom.xml is available for the artifact.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a misnomer, maven 3 does look in maven2 repositories -- there's no difference, except that, IIRC, maven 3 lacks support for the legacy repository layout.
2. No, it's not IDEAs fault.
3. install it as a 3rd party JAR using [mvn install:install-file -Dfile=log4j-2.0b7.jar -DgroupId=org.apache -DartifactId=log4j -Dversion=2.0b7 -Dpackaging=jar](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Good luck and if you have further problems, feel free to leave a comment.